# BackboneJS - get specific value from collection using _.max method

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to get a specific value from a model inside a Collection. The Collection is sorted by ID (contest_id) which is served by the database and gets delivered as JSON. So, the JSON looks like:

```
data : [{
     "contest_id" : "3",
     "artist" : {
        "artist_name": "some name",
        "artist_cover" : "some image.jpg"
      }
    },
    "contest_id" : "1",
    ....
}]
```

Now, I have glued something together:

```
var contestImage = _.max(this.collection.toJSON(), function(cnt){
    return cnt.contest_id;
});
```

I get the highest contest_id, which is what I want but how do I proceed when I want to grab the image? and even display it?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually made it work:

```
var contestImage = _.max(this.collection.toJSON(), function(cnt){
    return cnt.contest_id;
});
var latestImage = contestImage.artist.artist_cover;
```

Thanks for the answers though :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `max` method should actually be available directly from your Backbone collection (although it's an Underscore method, it's mixed into Backbone's Collections), which means you can simplify your code a bit.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var model = this.collection.max(function (cnt) {
    return cnt.contest_id;
});
var contest_id = model.get('contest_id');
```

The first section returns the model you want, and the second gets the contest ID attribute.

To get the artist cover attribute, you can then convert it to JSON:

```
var artist_cover = model.toJSON().artist.artist_cover;
```

Or get the artist attribute from the model:

```
var artist_cover = model.get('artist').artist_cover;
```

Comment: should this be defined inside the collection? inside `initialize`?

Comment: You could place it in the collection or the view - Backbone is fairly lax about things like that. It doesn't belong in the `initialize` method, though. I would probably place it in a dedicated method in your collection and call it when required from your view.

Comment: Hmm ok, because using your example I get `undefined is not a function`

Comment: @SHT Well, in that case you need to use your browser's JavaScript debugger to find what's going wrong. In principle my solution does what you've asked for - I've checked it myself and it works perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: @SHT The problem is quite obviously caused by something outside of the snippets you've provided, and is outside the scope of your question. You really need to learn to [ask better questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want Stack Overflow to be a useful resource for you.

Comment: Yes, I wil ltry to do better questions in the future! Thanks for the help anyway! I really appreciate it! :-)

Comment: No problem. As I said, in principle, this solution does work, but you may need to use the JavaScript debugger to track down the exact nature of your problem. I recommend the one in Chrome - there's a tutorial at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging that's very useful, and for things like Backbone it's indispensable

Comment: Also, there's a handy [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backbone-debugger/bhljhndlimiafopmmhjlgfpnnchjjbhd/related?hl=en) for debugging Backbone applications